# PDFBox 2.0.4 - Blank page (200+ inches height) with Adobe Reader 2015

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, adobe-reader

I have a very big screenshot (48.69 x 1220.93 cm) which I’m converting to PDF using `PDFBox 2.0.4`.

It works well when I open the generated PDF using the Mac Preview app, but not with Adobe Reader version 2015. It shows only a long blank page and says the dimensions are 19.17 x 200 inches. I’m aware that early versions of the PDF spec had a limit of 200 inches height. So I've tried setting the pdf version to 1.7 but it didn’t work:

```
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument#setVersion
org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument#setVersion
```

Both Adobe and Preview say the version of the pdf is 1.7. I can normally open smaller pdfs using adobe.

Comment: Please share the pdf.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, [This is the pdf I'm talking about](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uz622k2gtcpm4u1/121882.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: The media box is 1380 x 34609. 1 unit = 1/72 inch.  So it's about 19" x 480" or 48cm x 1211cm thus your assumptions are correct. I looked into the PDF with NOTEPAD++ and it is indeed 1.7. It is displayed blank in Adobe Reader. I didn't try to click the yellow bar. It displays in properly in PDFBox and in two other java based products. It crashes in gsview but works in ghostscript alone. If you don't get a better answer / comment, I'd suggest you complain at Adobe.

Answer (score 2):

As @Tilman already said in his comment,

> The media box is 1380 x 34609. 1 unit = 1/72 inch

Unfortunately this is beyond the size a specification conforming pdf reader has to support:

> The minimum  page  size  should  be  3  by  3  units  in  default  user  space;  the  maximum  should  be  14,400  by 14,400  units.  In  versions  of  PDF  earlier  than  1.6,  the  size  of  the  default  user  space  unit  was fixed  at  1 ⁄ 72 inch, yielding  a  minimum of  approximately 0.04  by  0.04 inch and  a maximum  of  200 by  200  inches. Beginning  with  PDF 1.6, the size of the unit may be  set on a page-by-page  basis; the  default remains at 1/ 72  inch.

*(Table  C.1  –   Architectural limits - ISO 32000-1)*

To support a document page as large as desired here, one should use a larger default user space unit, e.g. 3/72".